# Prove that $\dim(V) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\dim(K_{i}/K_{i-1})}\\$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Hello everyone I found the following statement and I don't see why it's actually true.

> Let $V$ be a vector space ( finite dimension ) and let $K_{0},...K_{n}$ be subspaces of $V$ with $$K_{0} = \left\{0 \right\} ,K_{1} ,\ldots , K_{n-1} , K_{n}=V,$$  and such that ....
>
> $$K_{0}\subseteq K_{1} \subseteq K_{2}\subseteq\cdots\subseteq K_{n-1} \subseteq K_{n},$$
> Then we have
> $$\dim(V) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\dim(K_{i}/K_{i-1})}\\$$

If anyone could help, thanks in advance

Comment: Use the fact that $\dim(K_i/K_{i-1})=\dim(K_i)-\dim(K_{i-1})$. The result should follow quickly.

Comment: Hint: Choose bases. The hypothesis that the subspaces form an ascending chain is quite strong.

Comment: @M.Nestor so at the end we have only $dim(V) = 0 + dim(V)$ left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \dim (K_i/K_{i-1}) = \sum_{i=1}^n (\dim K_i - \dim K_{i-1})= \dim K_n - \dim K_0 = \dim V$$